# Overloading the [] operator for creating a certain object instead of the built-in empty list

Tags: python, overloading, interpreter

Say I'm subclassing the built-in Python list like so:

```
class MyList(list):
    pass
```

Can you get Python to interpret something like the next line:

```
new_list = []
```

as a creation of an empty `MyList` instead of the empty built-in `list`, within the code itself.

I assume this is bad practice if it means that I have to alter the interpreter, unless there's a way I can explicitly tell it to do it from within my code.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. You can't override literals, they're not an operator.

Comment: seems logical. was just curious whether its possible. thank you for the answer.